# sum the values at the end of duplicate strings (special format) [UNIX]

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to find a commend or an idea for a script which does the following:
Consider the following example of the content of a file:

```
a,b,c,d,5
x,y,d,4,9
l,s,y,10
s,9
some,text,does,not,matter,15
```

the rule is simple: a bunch of strings separated (possible numbers but no commas) with commas in between and a number at the end: `str,str,str,...,number`

I know how to sort the file using the `sort` command, but I would like to sum all the lines with the same string until the number. consider the following example:

```
a,b,c,d,e,5
a,b,c,d,4
a,b,c,d,e,10
```

output will be:

```
a,b,c,d,e,15
a,b,c,d,4
```

order of the lines isn't important.

I think that the first step is to sort the file. then we should somehow split the lines and get the values so we could sum them, but how?

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "," }
     { num = $NF; $NF = ""; a[$0] += num }
     END{ for (i in a) print i a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,15
a,b,c,d,4
```